# Get the total amount of orders for a given product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I'm using WooCommerce and I've been using this code :

```
$units_sold = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'total_sales', true );
```

This meta returns the number of items sold. Therefore if someone buys two items, then, it returns two. And I want to get the number of orders for one product, not the number of units sold.

Do you know how can I have this number easily and in an efficient way?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a custom function that will return the number of orders for one product. You have a **`$product_id`** as argument in it:

```
function get_orders_count_for_a_product( $product_id ){

    $orders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'post_status' => array('wc-completed') // completed status only
    ) );

    $count_orders = 0;
    foreach($orders as $order){
        $has_product = false;
        foreach($order->get_items() as $item_values)
            if( $item_values['product_id'] == $product_id )
                $has_product = true;
        if( $has_product )
            $count_orders++;
    }
    return $count_orders;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> **USAGE:**
>
> ```
> // Here Product ID is 125
> $the_product_id = 125; 
> $number_of orders = get_orders_count_for_a_product($the_product_id);
> // Output the value
> echo 'Number of orders for product ID ' . $the_product_id . ' is: '. $number_of orders;
> ```

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec! I really appreciate all your help, thanks again.